# Errors when displaying QML Combobox contents

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm making a QML app. I'm populating a QML Combobox using this code.

```
DelegateChoice {
    roleValue: "AUTOCOMPLETADO"
    ComboBox {
        Layout.row: index
        Layout.column: 1
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        //textRole: datoValor
        model: ListModel {
            Component.onCompleted: {
                    for ( var k=0; k<5; ++k )
                        this.append({ text: "valor " + k } );
                    }
            }
        }
        editable: true
        //placeholderText: nombreCampo
        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            r2.model.get( index ).datoValor = this.text;
        }

    }
}
```

This works well in Windows but when I run this on Android it show an empty combobox and the output show these errors:

```
W IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what is `r2`? Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: r2 is a  model from a delegate chooser

Answer (score 0):

This code in Combobox solve problem:

```
editable: popup.visible ? false : true
```